# Catching Specific FaultExceptions in WF 4

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, faultexception

I am trying to set up a try catch block in Workflow 4 that is attempting to calling out to another service. This service could throw a number of specific, generically typed fault exceptions:

`FaultException<MySpecificFault>`

In the try catch I want to have a series of catches to deal with each one individuality. However, whenever attempt to catch a fault of the specific type, like I have above, it will in all cases fall through to the generic FaultException at the end of the block.

Is there something I am missing. Is this possible to do in WF4?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple catch block for a single try and each catch block can be configured to handle specific fault.
1. Choose browse for type in exception box in catch block.
2. Type "System.ServiceModel.FaultException" in selection box.
3.  Select specific fault from small combo box.

Comment: Hey, Vivek thanks, but catching specifically typed faults is the thing that is not working. If I use the specify the correct fault in the catch, and even verify that this is the case at runtime, it will never catch, it always falls through. I believe that this is a bug in Visual Studio in WF4, it seems that when you add a reference to an external service, the code generation for the service activity is failing to account for faults properly.